# Convert string to int with 1st null saving

Tags: java, string, integer, int

Usually Integer.valueOf(), Integer.parseInt() works perfect. But i have problem if in a String object are some nulls(0), here is some code.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.append("0");
    sb.append(9);

    Integer afterConvert = Integer.valueOf(sb.toString());
    System.out.println(afterConvert);
```

This code shows "9", but i need "09". Is any way to achieve it?

Comment: 09 is same 9 but why do you need 09?Any specific reasons?

Comment: see System.out.printf

Comment: JQueryLearner yep, specific reasons..

Comment: i need "09" in the afterConvert variable, not on display :D

Comment: Why do you need "09" as an integer? it doesn't even an integer!

Comment: You can't have "09" in an `Interger` variable, but in a `String`! So you have to format the output.

Comment: Side note, integers starting with `0` are octal representations, so you cannot assign an int variable with value `09` directly. A decimal integer with value `9` **should** be represented as `9`.

Comment: Check this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023699/java-how-to-format-a-number-to-a-2-char-string

Comment: Why aren't you just doing `System.out.println(sb);` on the last line?

Comment: After Integer.valueOf the knowledge about leading zeroes is gone. You'll need to keep the string or if you know how many zeroes there are you can format according during output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with null values.

The Integer value of 09 is 9.

If you want to print leasing zeros, use:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%02d", afterConvert));
```

See similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/275715/1651233).

Comment: as i understand that is way for DISPLAYING "09", but in fact afterConvert has "9" value?

Comment: You are right. There is no meaning for integer to be 09, it can only be 9.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot print Integer with leading 0s like this. You can use NumberFormat class:

```
NumberFormat nb = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nb.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
System.out.println(nb.format(afterConvert));
```